# How to handle generic types in GraphQl-Java?

Tags: java, graphql-java

I try to convert our model into a GraphQL schema using the following resolver:

```
@Component
public class QueryResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    public List<Result> results;
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Type java.util.List cannot be
>   mapped to a GraphQL type!  Since GraphQL-Java deals with erased types
>   at runtime, only non-parameterized classes can represent a GraphQL
>   type.  This allows for reverse-lookup by java class in interfaces and
>   union types.

How may I get around this problem,  since I need to use generic types?

Comment: The error message is very misleading. The limitation doesn't come from graphql-java at all, but from the way the library you're using (seems to be graphql-java-tools) works, and how Java works, to a certain extent. I unfortunately don't know enough about that library to help you, but I can recommend either using graphql-java directly as it now provides schema-first design features out-of-the-box (so much less need for graphql-java-tools) or [GraphQL SPQR](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr) if you want to map Java to GraphQL types (my project), as it has no issues with generic types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get that error above, check your schema files, if the `return types` of your fields are correct! In my case it was just caused by missing brackets:

Change:

```
list(page: Int = 0, size: Int = 10): Result!
```

To:

```
list(page: Int = 0, size: Int = 10): [Result]!
```